# Назначние функций redis

Tags: golang, redis

Наткнулся на [ресурс](https://kb.objectrocket.com/redis/how-to-use-redis-go-client-go-redis-redis-with-golang-592). <s>Скопировал</s> Написал все функции что и там и мне кажется все как то просто слишком. Обычно это бывает когда неправильно все понимаю.

Поправьте меня если ошибаюсь

Функция `Set(rClient)` кэширует данные

Функция `Get(rClient)` достает данные с кэша?

Если так то в чем подвох, почему так просто выглядит все?

Я нуб и возможно это глупый вопрос.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

func main() {
    Set(rClient())
    Get(rClient())
    ping(rClient())
}

func rClient() *redis.Client {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr: "localhost:6379",
    })

    return client
}

func ping(client *redis.Client) error {
    pong, err := client.Ping().Result()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(pong, err)

    return nil
}

func Set(client *redis.Client) error {
    err := client.Set("name", "maksim", 0).Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return nil
}

func Get(client *redis.Client) error {
    name, err := client.Get("name").Result()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(name)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, всё именно так просто. Redis - это не-SQL база данных, которая, помимо всего прочего, реализует `key-value storage`, то есть просто хранит пары `(key, value)`.

Вы в функции `Set` связываете ключ `name` со значением `maxim`, а в функции `Get` возвращаете значение, связанное с `name`. Вот и всё. Накаких `insert`, никаких `select`.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что по сути эти функции готовы к использованию в реальном приложении?

Comment: Какие именно? Функции `client.Set` и `client.Get` - да, готовы. Но для эффективного использования редиса нужно для начала освоить ключевые концепции. В реальных приложениях помимо Get и Set используются ещё как минимум две операции -- проверка что ключ существует и итерация по множеству ключей. Итерация в редисе сделана зело небанально, не так, как во многих других key-value базах.